# Style Standard Chatter Components

Tags: apex, chatter, sfdc-styleguide

I have a requirement where i need to restyle the chatter component of sfdc like chatter:newsfeed> but problem is with standardstyle sheet as false some of the allignment is disturbed and also some buttons like share dont work.

When i go other route where say i need to built UI similar to chatter ,Is there any previous code that i can enhance upon ?

Also whats the best startegy for data population ?connect API or chatter REST directly will speed my development  ?

Comment: What did you end up doing?  I'm pulling the chatter feed and it is destroying pretty much the entire site with its custom, non-prefixed css